# go-ethereum change source code

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to change source code in `go-ethereum` so that I can learn how it works.

- Let's say in `flags.go` file, there's `log.Info("Set global gas cap", "cap", cfg.RPCGasCap)`, so I change the string `set global gas cap` to `My test`.
- Then I run `make all` ...
- Then I run `geth --ropsten console`.

The problem is when it starts, it still shows the old string - `set global gas cap` instead of `my test`. It doesn't matter what I change in source code, the same issue happens.

What am I missing ?

**UPDATE:**

- I have `GOPATH` set to `/Users/jordan/go` .
- in `/Users/jordan/go`, There's `bin` and `pkg` folders and also there's `src` folder and my ethereum code is placed in `/Users/jordan/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`.
- I change the code and do `make all`. I also try another approach - I go to `cmd/geth` and I do `go build ./` and then use the built `geth`.
- I run `geth --ropsten console` and my changed code still doesn't take any effect at all.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing "make clean" before "make"?

Comment: go to `./cmd/geth` and do `go build ./` in that dir. Use the binary created in this dir

Comment: do not use make

Comment: Thanks guys. Do you think I need to change import statements from `github.com/ethereum/...` to `github.com/myrepo/...` ?

Comment: and btw, all the flags are set in `cmd/util`

Comment: just copy `go-ethereum` to $HOME/go/src/github/ethereum` and modify ethereum sources all you want. It is going to take the sources from this local path

Comment: the change of the `import` statements is not needed. you are just going to create a big mess, just copy ethereum sorces to local Go directory

Comment: do I still need the gopath if I am using Mac ?

Comment: @Nulik I updated my question following your suggestion

Comment: DONE. I made it. Seems like my `updated` version works

Comment: the invocation of binaries in linux is using `./`  to run the binary in current directory, so you cant just run `geth`, you need to invoke it as `./geth`

Comment: What would be the the analog of `make all` since I sometimes want to change `evm code` too